# Kali Linux: wrong kernel. What to do?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, install, reinstall

What does this mean :
Unable to boot- please use a kernel appropriate for your  CPU 
what do I have to do ?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is your computer a 32 bit or a 64 bit?

Comment: 32bit
it works but now I have another problem , installation system failed

Comment: @WAI are you installing it on a vm?

Comment: did you mean  "video memory" ?!

Comment: @WAI are u installing it on a virtual machine or as a dual boot?

Comment: virtual machine

Comment: @WAI make sure you allocate enough memory in the virtual machine settings. Try a different copy of kali 2.0. Also make sure you downloaded the ISO file from official kali websites.

Comment: The video memory was 16mb , I thought to change it to 60mb , has it a copulative ?! 
it's now downloading

Comment: if it stops downloading , I will try what you told me :)
thank you so much : )

Comment: Do let me know if your facing challenges. I will guide you step by step.

Comment: OMG , I don't know what I have to say to you , I really appreciate that : )
I will download kali 2.0  from official kali  websites.
I think it will work .

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are most likely trying to run 64-bit version of Kali on a 32-bit CPU. Try downloading and using a 32-bit version of Kali.